# showing Html content in textview

Tags: html, string, uitextview, editing

I have to show html string in textview not in uiwebview. Because i have to edit the content of the html string.

for ex:

NSString *data="< br>Data to be shown<\   br>"

textview.text= data;

Is it possible?
Thanks in advance for suggestion

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 1):

like this ?

```
UITextView * text = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 0.0f , 0.0f, 100.0f, 150.0f)];
text.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
text.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[text setValue:@"<b>big</b><br>blah blah" forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
[text sizeToFit];

[imageButton addSubview:text];
```

Comment: Were you able to get this through app store approval?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can show the HTML text, but it will just be displayed as plaintext source. UITextView does not support any "rich-editing" or display out of the box.